# SwiftUI: Best approach for fetching data and passing to SubViews?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

I have a parent view `DetailView` and I want to query for heart rates during a workout.  After I get back the heart rates I want to pass them to a child View.  The code below, the heart rates aren't getting passed to `HeartRateRecoveryCard` ?

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State var heartRateSamples: [HKQuantitySample] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        HeartRateRecoveryCard(heartRateSamples: heartRateSamples)
            .onAppear {
                getHeartRatesFromWorkout()
            }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    private func getHeartRatesFromWorkout() {
        
        guard let workout = SelectedWorkoutSingleton.sharedInstance.selectedWorkout else { return }
        
        print("workout = \(workout.startDate)")
        
        WorkoutManager.getHeartRateSamplesFrom(workout: workout) { (samples, error) in
            
            guard let unwrappedSamples = samples else {
                print("no HR samples")
                return }
            
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print("error attempting to get heart rates = \(unwrappedError)")
            }
            
            print("we have \(unwrappedSamples.count) heart rates")
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                heartRateSamples = unwrappedSamples
            
            }
        }
    }

    
}


struct HeartRateRecoveryCard: View {

    //Don't download HR samples for this view the parent view should download HR samples and pass them into it's children views
     @State var heartRateSamples: [HKQuantitySample]
    @State var HRRAnchor = 0
    @State var HRRTwoMinutesLater = 0
    @State var heartRateRecoveryValue = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(heartRateRecoveryValue) bpm")
            Text("\(HRRAnchor) bpm - \(heartRateRecoveryValue) bpm")
            SwiftUILineChart(chartLabelName: "Heart Rate Recovery", entries: convertHeartRatesToLineChartDataAndSetFormatter(heartRates: heartRateSamples).0, xAxisFormatter: convertHeartRatesToLineChartDataAndSetFormatter(heartRates: heartRateSamples).1)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 180, alignment: .center)
                .onAppear {
                    print("heart rate count = \(heartRateSamples.count)")
                    if let unwrappedHRRObject =  HeartRateRecoveryManager.calculateHeartRateRecoveryForHRRGraph(heartRateSamples: heartRateSamples) {
                        HRRAnchor = unwrappedHRRObject.anchorHR
                        HRRTwoMinutesLater = unwrappedHRRObject.twoMinLaterHR
                        heartRateRecoveryValue = unwrappedHRRObject.hrr
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you have a lot of debugging info. What prints in the console when you run this?

Comment: Don't use `@State`. Use an observable model object with published properties. Share that model object to your detail view and magic happens 

Comment: @Paulw11 this is an existing app that I didn't really want to get into rewriting with Combine right now but I can if I have to, but why would publishers work better here than completion handlers? Shouldn't they both work?

Comment: @AaronBrager yes most notably my heart rate count = 0 in `HeartRateRecoveryCard` which tells me I'm not passing the data into it correctly

Comment: I am not talking about using Combine publishers directly.  I am talking about using `ObservableObject` and `@Published` properties (which, yes, is using Combine, but so is your current @State solution - SwiftUI uses Combine under the covers).  What I am talking about is architecting your SwiftIUI app properly;  A function like `getHeartRatesFromWorkout` doesn't belong in a view.  It belongs in a model.  If that model exposes an `@Published var heartRateSamples: [HKQuantitySample]` then you can bind your view to that property.  The subview can also bind to that model/property.

Comment: You should only use `@State` for state that is local to that view (You can also Use `@Binding` if you need to share some state across views, but I don't think that is appropriate in this case).

You could also use the environment to avoid the singleton anti-pattern, but that isn't as important as separating your model and your view.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 I will refactor and build a new ViewModel to manage the model data.